# How to send numbers in User Attributes on Firebase?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-analytics

I'm trying to send numbers in my Firebase application to send notification to specific users and I noticed that we can use numbers but there's only this function to send string data

```
FIRAnalytics.setUserPropertyString(numberOfOrders, forName: TrackingConstants.UserAttributeKeys.NumberOfOrders)
```

[image]

Is there an other function for sending numbers or does Firebase threat any numbers sent as a string like a number once it receives the data? I could not find any documentation on how to use numbers for User Attributes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the operators on the UserProperty just like Numbers even though it is set as a string.

Comment: You are right. I wasn't receiving it because of a plist configuration...